# DataGridView RowValidation e.Cancel Locks UI

Tags: vb.net, winforms, validation, datagridview

We have this WinForm application where we validates the entries in the data grid.

By Applying the business rules in the RowValidating event of the DataGridView we set the ErrorText property of the DataGridViewRow and set e.Cancel=True.

This shows the error notification icon on the DataGrid Row user is working with, however, we now notice that user cannot enter any input in the text box (either in the same Form, or opening another Form). It seems like DataGridView blocks the input and does not allow user to enter any data.

We are trying to understand why this is happening and how this can be rectified please.

Comment: We shouldn't have to ask you to post the actual code. We can't test your code without your code.

Comment: What's the best way to upload whole solution (zipped file) here please?

Comment: I understand the uploading/giving code helps to understand the problem better, however, my understanding is that this is something someone would have come across before. Therefore, I thought it would be easier for someone to just say that "This is a solution of your issue".

Comment: No one wants the whole solution. Post the RELEVANT code. You said the issue occurs because of the code in the `RowValidating` event handler. It should be obvious that you need to post THAT code.

Comment: Here is the code. Here you see that we are setting ErrorText property in RowValidating and setting e.Canel=True. After setting this when user moves to other FORM that he/she cannot enter any data in the text box. Thanks.


Private Sub dgvMain_RowValidating(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles dgvMain.RowValidating

        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = dgvMain.Rows(e.RowIndex)

        '--- Apply some business rules here and they don't pass then set the ErrorText property.
        row.ErrorText = "Some Error Details"

        e.Cancel = True

    End Sub

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to Format code here. :(

Comment: Don't post code of anything more than a single, short line in a comment and then format it. If you don't know how to use the site properly, read the instructions. Post the code where it should have been to begin with: in the question. Edit your question and add the code, formatting it appropriately.

Comment: I do really wonder how the heck can edit this question as it does not allow me here when I am writing these comments :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169338/discussion-between-asfand-iqbal-and-jmcilhinney).

Comment: The discussion is at an end. Post the code.

Comment: I have posted the code previously; all we can do is to extract that code and put them in text box and format it. This will give you clear picture of what piece of code is causing this issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have uploaded the code; https://ufile.io/iwmgh